# How to submit radio button value via jQuery post()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

What I am trying to do is to grab the radio button value and submit it via jQuery post() into a php file and get a response.

The below code works fine when I'm trying to sent the value for the "city". As you can see the "test" is commented out. With the "test" being commented out the program works and the value for "city" gets submitted to the php file gets processed, returned and printed.

Could anybody spot the problem with getting the radio button value?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#trans_type").click(function(){
    $('#realty_type').html("<b>Loading response...</b>");

    $.post("sql_s.php",
    {
      //  test: $('input[name=transaction_type]:checked', '#trans_type').val()
    city:"New York"
    },
    function(data,status){
    document.getElementById("object_type").innerHTML = data;
    });
  });
});
</script>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Some title</h1><br />

<form action="" id="trans_type">
<b>What would you like?</b><br />
<input type="radio" name="transaction_type" value="2">Sell&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="transaction_type" value="3">Buy
</form>
<div id="object_type">message comes here</div>


</body>
</html>
```

​

Comment: Did it not work with the line you have as comment? you just forgot the `,` after i supose...

Comment: TAT WAS IT!!!!!!!!!!!! after 2 hours of chasing my tail around!!!

Comment: Did you need your radio button value while checked radio button ?else you need to send both value means you should put Comma separator for each values...

Comment: Yes I needed the checked radio button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I supose the line you have in your code, commented, is what you want.
Just add a comma (`,`) since its a object and that is the separator you need...

So, use:

```
{
    test: $('input[name=transaction_type]:checked', '#trans_type').val(), // <- comma here
    city:"New York"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to change that line

```
{
    test: $('input[name=transaction_type]:checked', '#trans_type').val(), 
    city:"New York"
},
```

replace into

```
 {
        test: $('input[name=transaction_type]:checked').val(), 
        city:"New York"
    },
```

No need to put that Current `ID`
and also add comma separator `(,)` atlast your posted values for differentiate your values.
Refer this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkt91/0n1cg551/1/)